# How to store the state of an accordion that is using angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, accordion, angular-local-storage

I am using accordion directive from angular-bootstrap. I want to store the `is-open` attribute of this accordion , so if users goes another page on the website, the state of accordion i.e. `is-open` does not change. I can not find a resource which helps me manipulating the attribute directive.

```
<accordion-group heading="Main Information" is-open="true">
```

Comment: it depends on your browser but on my last project, we use the local storage for this. You can set your value in and get it back when you come bakc on your page

Comment: not hard to do with a simple angular service that could also be connected to localStorage as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an angular Service to store the state of the accordion, or just stick it into `$rootScope` for a quick fix.

In your angular module run function:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
  // set your default here, true for open, false for closed
  $rootScope.accordionOpen = true;
});
```

In your HTML:

```
<accordion-group heading="Main Information" is-open="accordionOpen">
```

This will persist across routes and such, but not a browser refresh. If you want to persist across a browser refresh, your module run function should be:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
  // set your default here, true for open, false for closed
  localStorage.accordionOpen = localStorage.accordionOpen || true
  $rootScope.accordionOpen = Boolean(localStorage.accordionOpen);
  $rootScope.toggleAccordion = function() {
    localStorage.accordionOpen = !Boolean(localStorage.accordionOpen);
  });
});
```

And in your HTML:

```
<accordion-group heading="Main Information" ng-click="toggleAccordion()" is-open="accordionOpen">
```

Change `localStorage` to `sessionStorage` if you want it to be cleared when the browser tab is closed. The reason for `Boolean()` is because localstorage can only store type `String`.